# Error using == Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab

my system will give me the a/m error when I input more than 3 characters

```
a = input('Please type f0 or f1: ' , 's');

if a == 'f0'; 
    Run_f0
elseif a == 'f1';
    Run_f1 
else 
    disp('Please enter f0 or f1 only');
end
```

what should I do to resolve this error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Matlab will compare each character of both strings. If one string is longer than the other one, there is nothing to compare and it will throw an error. You can bypass this by forcing the user to repeat the input until he gives a valid input:

```
valid = {'f0', 'f1'}
a = input('Please type f0 or f1: ' , 's');
while not(ismember(a, valid))  %// or: while not(any(strcmp(a, valid)))
    a = input('Please really type f0 or f1: ' , 's');
end
```

The user will be asked to really input 'f0' or 'f1'.

As an alternative, you can consider to compare the strings with `strcmp()`:

```
if strcmp(a, 'f0')
    %// something
elseif strmpc(a, 'f1')
    %// something else
else
    disp('Please enter f0 or f1 only');
end
```

Comment: Why would you prefer using ismember over strcmp? Or is the order of those answers arbitrary?

Comment: @sobek Well you are correct, Sir. The ``while not(ismember(a, valid))`` part can be rewritten to ``while not(any(strcmp(a, valid))``. Two solutions because you either have to make sure the input is valid in order to be then compared with ``==`` as the TO used it OR you have to work with invalid inputs and make sure the comparison works. I try to change as little code as possible to make the original code work.

Comment: Rgr, i just find the 2nd solution in your answer superior in just about every way, readability, performance (i figure), etc.

Comment: @sobek while I agree that strmpc is easier to read and maybe better regarding performance the ismember solution allows him to directly compare hundreds of arguments with the input. So if you just want to check rather its an allowed input I think ismember is better. But it depends on the number of ifcases you would have to check otherwise

Answer (score 1):

To compare strings you should use the function **strcmp**

```
a='12345'
strcmp('f01',a)
```

Returns: 0 (False)

```
a='f01'
strcmp('f01',a)
```

Returns: 1 (True)